# select the customer who does not attend an event using oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this scenario . I've got a customer who book a ticket to attend an event . I want to select customer who does not attend an event in glasgow . So I use

My table structure is

```
Customer (CUS_ID,CUS_NAME,GENDER, TEL_NO,ADDRESS)
EVENT (EVT_ID,VENUE_ID,DATE)
BOOKING (CUS_ID,EVT_ID)
VENUE (VENUE_ID,VENUE_NAME)

SQL> SELECT DISTINCT C.CUS_NAME
  2  FROM CUSTOMER C
  3  FULL OUTER JOIN BOOKING B ON C.CUS_ID = B.CUS_ID
  4  FULL OUTER JOIN EVENT E ON E.EVENT_ID = B.EVENT_ID
  5  FULL OUTER JOIN VENUE V ON V.VENUE_ID = E.VENUE_ID
  6  WHERE V.VENUE_NAME != 'GLASGOW';

CUS_NAME                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                                            

HENRY                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
CHRISINE                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
JENET                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
JOY
```

Expect result should be

```
CUS_NAME
---------------------

HENRY
CHRISTINE
```

Because JANET and JOY went to the event .

The problem was some customer did go to glasgow but they also attend some other events . So when I use the above query it return them as well.

Anyone know how can I fix this?

Comment: Please show your table structure and some input and expected output.

Comment: You're providing no where near enough information for people to help you. What do the tables look like?

Comment: hi there , sorry I just updated my queries. Hope you guys can help me .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT CUS_NAME  
FROM CUSTOMER 
WHERE CUS_NAME NOT IN (

                        SELECT DISTINCT C.CUS_NAME
                        FROM CUSTOMER C
                        FULL OUTER JOIN BOOKING B ON C.CUS_ID = B.CUS_ID
                        FULL OUTER JOIN EVENT E ON E.EVENT_ID = B.EVENT_ID
                        FULL OUTER JOIN VENUE V ON V.VENUE_ID = E.VENUE_ID
                        WHERE V.VENUE_NAME = 'GLASGOW';

                      )
```

The inner query returns customers who visited Glasgow and outer query excludes them

Answer (score 1):

I *think* you want to select customers who did not attend an event in Glasgow, without selecting customers who attended Glasgow along with events in other cities. If that's the case, something like this should work.

```
SELECT c.customer_id, ...
  FROM customer c
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 'X'
                     FROM booking b
                     JOIN event e ON e.event_id = b.event_id
                     JOIN venue v ON v.venue_id = e.venue_id
                    WHERE b.cus_id = c.cus_id
                      ANd v.venue_name = 'glasgow'
                   )
```